# Does not execute the code after a for within a function

Tags: javascript, function, iteration

Good! I have a problem and you do not run my code at the end of the loop, the above and what is inside the loop works fine, the problem is that after the loop is still not executing the code. Any idea why it can be?

This is my code:

```
var arrayp = new Array();
function botonAdelante(tabl, pasos)
{
  var padreTabla = document.getElementById(tabl).rows;
  var cont = 0;

  for(var j = 0; j < padreTabla.length; j++)
  {
    var hijoTd = document.getElementById(pasos+ "-producto-" +j);
    var childArray = hijoTd.children;
    for(var i = 0; i < childArray.length; i++)
    {
      var check = document.getElementById(pasos+ "-CheckBox-" +j);
      if(check.type == 'checkbox' && check.checked==true)
      {
        arrayp[cont] = check.value;
        var algo = arrayp[cont];

        alert(arrayp[cont]);
        alert(arrayp);

        cont++;
        continue;
      };
    }
  }
  alert("It is in this part of the code does not work");
}
```

Clarification: "continue" found at the end of long and if it will not work either.

Comment: what is the purpose of continue? what is not executing? the alert?

Comment: Exactly, what does not work is the alert

Comment: You have two loops.  Which one is not working?  Also, do you mean `break;` instead of `continue;`?

Comment: The two loops work, what does not work is the alert which was then located the two loops. The put it continue because I found it online, but if it out does not work anyway

Comment: Do you see console errors? Are you sure you want `children` rather than `childNodes`?

Comment: that could depend on the browser

Comment: Eh not reviewed in the console, and if I want children, and not the childNodes

Comment: My browser is google chrome

Comment: I'd recommend stepping through this in the debugger and figuring out exactly where it stops executing.  I'm fairly sure there's an error happening which stops the script.

Answer (score 0):

The continue is confusing used like this, but I have a feeling your code is probably throwing an error because the cont might exceed the array length. Regardless of whether this fixes it or not I'd at least add a check to ensure that it doesn't throw an exception.

Please check for exceptions being thrown through web dev tools (F12 in Chrome).

```
        for(var i = 0; i < childArray.length; i++)
        {
            var check = document.getElementById(pasos+ "-CheckBox-" +j);
            if(check.type == 'checkbox' && check.checked==true && arrayp.length <= cont)
            {
                arrayp[cont] = check.value;
                var algo = arrayp[cont];

                alert(arrayp[cont]);
                alert(arrayp);

                cont++;
                continue;
            };
        }
```

Comment: Eh added the condition in the if, but not worked. Now vere debug, but not very well as it is.

Comment: I think the problem is this: hijoTd var = document.getElementById (steps + "-products-" + j); I think within the for you can not create variables where the auto id increased with "j" will

Comment: You should check for nulls on dom elements too.

Comment: I check to check with if, but I think it iterates the loop because it does not overwrite the value of "j" found in getElementById (pasos + "-products-" + j);